# How to combine two json files with one common key,value

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have two json files with a key,value in common, and I would like to combine them making sure that the information of one slots into the other correctly.
So I have:

```
[
  {
  ["id": "fc4f",
   "data": [
  {
    "spk": "A",
    "utt": "Hello.",
    "meta": "abdbcbsb",
    "words": "sbdbe"
  },
  {
    "spk": "B",
    "utt": "Hello, how can I help you?",
    "meta": "etc etc",
    "words": "demdk"
  }]
},
{"id": "fc5f",
   "data": [
  {
    "spk": "A",
    "utt": "Okay then.",
    "meta": "de fw",
    "words": "dwerbj"
  },
  {
    "spk": "B",
    "utt": "Going on",
    "meta": "etc2 etc2",
    "words": "felm"
  }]
}
]
```

and the second file is like this, where the "id" and "utt" keys are in common:

```
[
  {
  ["id": "fc4f",
   "data": [
  {
    "utt": "Hello.",
    "number": "112"
  },
  {
    "utt": "Hello, how can I help you?",
    "number": "113"
  }]
},
{"id": "fc5f",
   "data": [
  {
    "utt": "Okay then.",
    "number": "11"
  },
  {
    "utt": "Going on",
    "number": "1"
  }]
}
]
```

And the result would ideally look like:

```
[
  {
  ["id": "fc4f",
   "data": [
  {
    "spk": "A",
    "utt": "Hello.",
    "meta": "abdbcbsb",
    "words": "sbdbe",
    "number": "112"
  },
  {
    "spk": "B",
    "utt": "Hello, how can I help you?",
    "meta": "etc etc",
    "words": "demdk",
    "number": "113"
  }]
},
{"id": "fc5f",
   "data": [
  {
    "spk": "A",
    "utt": "Okay then.",
    "meta": "de fw",
    "words": "dwerbj",
    "number": "1"
  },
  {
    "spk": "B",
    "utt": "Going on",
    "meta": "etc2 etc2",
    "words": "felm"
    "number": "11"
  }]
}
]
```

Because file2 might not have all the data in file1, I would need to make sure to skip those instances where the data doesn't match. I start with loading both files with `json.load()` but then I don't know how to go on. Can someone help?

Comment: Are you sure the json files are correct?

Comment: @ThisaruG I have edited the question so that the parenthesis make more sense but yes, basically the files are made up of dictionaries within a list within dictionaries